# jQuery :contains not working in ie7 (jQuery 1.3.5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to find a text inside a `div`. The code I have works in all browsers except IE7.

Below is the code:

```
<div class="demo"> 
   Preveiw
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".demo:contains('Preveiw').length") // returns 0 in IE7
```

Comment: You sure you haven't misspelled preview?

Comment: @HoshSadiq It is misspelled, however it's the same in both places so should still work.

Comment: My bad. jQuery 1.3.5 is rather old, maybe you should consider updating?

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead

```
$(".demo:contains('Preveiw')").length
```

Comment: Here's a fiddle with Stefan's answer: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Y7bG2/2/. I've tested it in IE7 and it does appear to work.

Comment: Are you running it once the DOM is loaded (ready)? Also notice that the `:contains` selector is case sensitive.

Comment: @Nitesh: Show us a testcase of your problem on jsfiddle.net. Too many inconsistencies here.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that jQuery has not loaded yet try putting your script at the bottom of the page within

```
 <script defer="defer">
```

which will rule that out and the code within

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        alert($(".demo:contains('Preveiw')").length);
  });
```

which could be another problem.

here it is on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kamui/VfhQ6/2/